# Situação curiosa ao inserir grid-area com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, foreach

Estou inserindo algumas estilizações em um projetinho que estou fazendo, e estou com um forEach rodando no DOM pra percorrer uma lista, acontece que se eu adiciono um grid-area e coloco o indice como valor do grid area, ele replica o valor 4 vezes. Talvez por texto não seja muito compreensível, vou demonstrar no código:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach((element, indice) => {
  element.style.cssText = `grid-area: item${indice}`
})
```

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width; 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-areas: "item0 item2 item3" "item4 item5 item6"
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px dashed;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Teste 1</li>
  <li>Teste 2</li>
  <li>Teste 3</li>
  <li>Teste 4</li>
  <li>Teste 5</li>
  <li>Teste 6</li>
</ul>
```

O que ele me retorna é isso:

```
<ul>
  <li style="grid-area: item0 / item0 / item0 / item0;">Teste 1</li>
  <li style="grid-area: item1 / item1 / item1 / item1;">Teste 2</li>
  <li style="grid-area: item2 / item2 / item2 / item2;">Teste 3</li>
  <li style="grid-area: item3 / item3 / item3 / item3;">Teste 4</li>
  <li style="grid-area: item4 / item4 / item4 / item4;">Teste 5</li>
  <li style="grid-area: item5 / item5 / item5 / item5;">Teste 6</li>
</ul>
```

Por que ele faz isso `item0 / item0 / item0 / item0`, se o forEach retorna o indice no parâmetro 2?

Comment: Segundo a MDN: [*The grid-area CSS property is a shorthand property for grid-row-start, grid-column-start, grid-row-end and grid-column-end*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Grid funciona como um plano cartesiano, onde cada célula tem um `X/Y` inicial e um `X/Y` final. Por isso ele repete 4x, na verdade ele está colocando o valor para `x inicial / y inicial / x final / y final`.

Se vc quer contornar isso vc pode colocar o style usando o `setAttribut` e colocando o index como valor do `grid-area` conforme abaixo

```js
document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach((element, i) => {
    element.setAttribute("style", "grid-area: item"+[i])
})
```

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width; 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-areas: "item0 item2 item3" "item4 item5 item6"
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px dashed;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Teste 1</li>
  <li>Teste 2</li>
  <li>Teste 3</li>
  <li>Teste 4</li>
  <li>Teste 5</li>
  <li>Teste 6</li>
</ul>
```

O resultado no DOM ficaria assim:

```
<ul>
    <li style="grid-area: item0">Teste 1</li>
    <li style="grid-area: item1">Teste 2</li>
    <li style="grid-area: item2">Teste 3</li>
    <li style="grid-area: item3">Teste 4</li>
    <li style="grid-area: item4">Teste 5</li>
    <li style="grid-area: item5">Teste 6</li>
</ul>
```

---

**Apenas para fins didáticos**

Esse gid área seria `grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ::Gif do Leo Stronda:: O maluco é Brabo. Valeu de novo hugão!

Comment: @LucasdeCarvalho esse é o bonda da maromba! Birllll 